# Salesforce Certifications

Tags: certification

Need guidance on which exam to opt for Salesforce as I have nearly 2 years of experience in Salesforce Administration as well as Development, in totality 9 years of experience in IT. I would like to become Salesforce Consultant.

Comment: This is probably too much of an opinion-based question. If you know you want to get Salesforce certified, you'll need to decide which route to go down: Admin or Dev. It's worth going to http://certification.salesforce.com/ to read what each cert contains, and probably even look at job boards to see what jobs require what certs to see what is best for you. Realistically, only you can make that choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce Certifications are industry recognised qualifications that prove to employers or clients that you excel in a certain field within Salesforce. There are multiple routes of Salesforce Qualifications, Administrator, Developer, Implementation Experts, App Builders, Architects, Pardot and Marketers. Each of these have different levels of qualifications. However, most users of Salesforce will take a similar route and order of qualifications.

The Salesforce Certified Administrator is where most users start, this provides you with the basics of Salesforce, its standard and custom objects, automation and most importantly, it’s security model. From there, users will most likely specialise depending on their personal career goals and vocation.

If you go to http://certification.salesforce.com/ there is lots of good information about the certification program. I would suggest you start with the basic admin and then you can move to the Consultant exams (Sales Cloud/Service Cloud etc). Salesforce Administrator is a good place to start as it will give you an overview of the platform and features. Good luck!